# JPA Parent entity ignore child entity versioning

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have 2 entity classes:

Parent one that contains 1-1 relation with child (no @Version for optimistic locking):

```
@Entity
public class Poo {
...
@OneToOne(cascade = ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "mapping_column")
private Foo foo;
...
}
```

and here is the child class (has @Version for optimistic locking):

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
...
@Version
@Column(name="optlock")
private Integer optLock;
...
}
```

When updating some fields of the parent entity, in between child entity got changed by another process, so optlock is increased as expected.

But that gives issues as it prevents an update of the parent entity, even if child is not touched by the update:

```
...
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction
...
```

Was wandering if there is more straight forward way to prevent checking versioning if child entity is not changed? because in the end there will be no update in the DB for it.

Comment: I have recreated your example, and I'm unable to reproduce your issue.,When I change an attribute on the parent without modifying the child, it works as expected, and there is only one update query which is for the parent entity. I'm using Hibernate 5.2.5.

Comment: I am on still Hibernate 3.6.0

Comment: Seriously, it is more than 6 years old. In my opinion you should never use any framework that is more than 2 years old (unless it is som proprietary stuff that is no longer developed). You have to periodically upgrade you dependencies (and JDK), or the technical debt becomes unmanageable. Make a standalone github example to see if you can reproduce it. If there is a bug, you will need to upgrade Hibernate anyway.